# In CSS, should I apply a font-size change to the top-level element, or the most bottom level one?

Tags: html, css

Which is more proper/faster?

For example, say I have a `DIV` with  `UL` in it, with five `LI` in it. Do I apply a font-size style and a font-family style to the `DIV`, `UL` or `LI`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the font size where it is applicable.

If you want all of the text in a `<div>` to be the same size, apply the font size there.

I also recommend using relative font sizes (`ems`).  This will generally save you some time.